# MS SQL - Find all table aliases from all views in certain schema or in all schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find all table aliases from all views in certain schema or in all schemas in DB?

I am dealing with tone of tables/views and all views are already containing aliases on tables. I would like to know if there is procedure to extract them with SQL.

What I would like to get is something similar to:

```
VIEW_NAME|TABLE_NAME|ALIAS_NAME
test_view|test_table|alias
```

I tried tone of stuff but non worked. Last thing I tried was [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic720044-145-1.aspx)

Comment: What about that query didn't work?

Comment: you can query all views where a table is used, but not the alias for that table in each view. That is not any system info so its not saved anywhere

Comment: A table alias is only valid inside a query, so why would you want to know about them?

Comment: I need to keep using them in new queries/views